# Issue with specialization and higher kinds in scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, higher-kinded-types

I have these lines (scala 2.11.11):

```
trait TypeClass[T]
class DoubleIsTypeClass extends TypeClass[Double]
implicit val forDouble = new DoubleIsTypeClass
```

Know lets add the following line :

```
case class User[V[_], @specialized T : TypeClass](a: V[T])
```

Now it does not compile.
Removing `@specialized` fixes it.
Is it a bug ?
I don't really need higher kinds here except their help with type inference but that is a big deal.

**EDIT**
Just for those who may have stumbled upon a similar problem

Typeclasses are not the issue here, case classes are:

```
case class User[V[_], @specialized T](a: V[T])
```

The line above does not compile on its own.

Comment: Provide more information on "does not compile". What's the compilation error? why do you need `@specialized`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [SI-9227](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9227). It seems to be a bug.

In general, these are [some quirks around specialization](http://axel22.github.io/2013/11/03/specialization-quirks.html) which are worth reading about.